# Get previous value after updated table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT status_id FROM requests WHERE id = 1; -- status id : 100 that is NEW.
```

Now I updated the requests record from the NEW status to OPEN status(Status_id is 101).
So do I get the old status id in any way after updating the record since the transaction is committed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trigger to get this OLD value, please check the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html)